# AngularJS select box value not set to default after a selection

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS , I'm having a select box with an option. When user selects option without checking check boxes I'm showing a message. It works ! But after that I want to set select option value to default. It's not working. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
  this.onChange = function (ev, selectoptionModel){
  if(selectoptionModel == "OK"){

    if(this.myArray.length==0){

      alert = $mdDialog.alert({
        title: 'Attention',
        textContent: 'Please select option first',
        ok: 'Close'
      });

      $mdDialog
        .show( alert )
        .finally(function() {
          alert = undefined;
          selectoptionModel = "";

        });
    }
  }
  }
```

Select Option

```
 <div>
  <md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="selectoptionModel" ng-change="$dataListController.onChange($event,selectoptionModel)" placeholder="Bulk Action">
        <md-option value="DONE">DONE</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show your full controller code? And you have only one option, then why you are using `select` box?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the **function parameter**, so it is not changing. **Instead change the scope variable.**

Since it is inside a function, you may not get the reference of `this`, so take a variable `vm` and assign `this` value into it and use inside function.

```
this.onChange = function (ev, selectoptionModel){
  var vm = this;    
  if(selectoptionModel == "OK"){

    if(this.myArray.length==0){

      alert = $mdDialog.alert({
        title: 'Attention',
        textContent: 'Please select option first',
        ok: 'Close'
      });

      $mdDialog
        .show( alert )
        .finally(function() {
          alert = undefined;
          $scope.selectoptionModel = ""; // If it didnt work, try below function
          $scope.$apply(function(){
             $scope.selectoptionModel = "";
          })  
          $window.location.reload();
        });
    }
  }
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div>
  <md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="selectoptionModel" ng-change="$dataListController.onChange($event,selectoptionModel)" placeholder="Bulk Action">
        <md-option value=""></md-option>
        <md-option value="DONE">DONE</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

</div>
```

Comment: Also I updated my question little bit. I removed window reload. Because it should not be there. Still the issue is same

Comment: do you have `$scope`? in your controller?

Comment: I'm working with someone's code. It's declared globally.

Comment: : $scope is not defined getting this error..after I define scope there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161783/discussion-between-sravan-and-coderaizer).